# How to get the value of imageview in tilepane, JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I made a tilepane in JavaFX. And I put some imageview on tilepane.

### tilepane => imageview => image

I want to get the value of image in imageview in tilepane(first row, first column).

this value

```
  ↓
```

### | 0,0  | 0,1  | 0,2  |  0,3 |  0,4 |

### | 1,0  |  1,1 |  1,2 |  1,3 |  1,4 |

I tried to

```
System.out.println(tilepane.getChildren().get(0))
```

=>  result : Pane@2fc42278

I can access to tilepane(first row, first column).
But I can't get the inner value. My final goal is getting the image's name.
How can I get the value of image?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Node has a method [setUserData](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setUserData%28java.lang.Object%29) into which you can put any object. You could assign the ImageView object a name via the setUserData method.

Iterating through the TitledPane would be like this:

```
    TitledPane pane = ...
    for( Node child: pane.getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
        if( child instanceof ImageView) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) child;
            System.out.println( imageView.getUserData());
        }
    }
```

That way you check for ImageView. But of course you could as well check the userData of all nodes without checking for ImageView.

Comment: Oh! It's very nice. Thanks a lot! I can get image url! And I'm sorry. I want vote,  but I lack of reputation.  ##

System.out.println( imageView.getImage().impl_getUrl());   ##

Comment: Don't use that. The impl_... methods are flagged to be removed in later versions. Unless there's another option, I suggest you put the url as UserData into the Node.

Comment: Ok! I will try! Have a nice weekend!