# JavaFX : How to make a mark where between two imageview in tilepane

Tags: javafx

I try to make a slide frame looks like powerpoint using imageview and tilepane.

Let's suppose we are in powerpoint. In photo, there are blue background panel(tilepane) and slide(imageview).

I want make a mark(line) that is red arrow pointed in photo, when I locate mouse cursor where between slide5 and slide6. Can I make?
[image]

And how to get the each hgap area's information?
ex) Which hgap clicked?
I can get the [each slide(imageview) value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240750/how-to-get-the-value-of-imageview-in-tilepane-javafx), but I can't find how to get the hgap's information.

This is my partial code.

```
String[] imageName = {"slide1.png", "slide2.png", "slide3.png", "slide4.png", 
                        "slide5.png", "slide6.png", "slide7.png", "slide8.png"};
    Image img = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < imageName.length; i++) {
        try {
            img = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imageName[i]));   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception : " + e);
        }
        ImageView imageview = new ImageView(img);
        imageview.setUserData(imageName[i]);
        imageview.setFitWidth(widthImageView);
        imageview.setFitHeight(heightImageView);

        HBox hbox= new HBox();
        hbox.getChildren().add(imageview);
        tile1.getChildren().add(hbox); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hgap and vgap parameters are used for calculating the space between the nodes. You can't put a node in there. You should evaluate your requirements and consider using a different layout like e. g. [GridPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html).

Comment: Oh! A good idea occured to me due to your answer. Thanks a lot! :)